# Why does this single and double precision comparison fail in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

Given:

```
val = 1e20
a = np.array(val); b = np.array(val, 'f4')
```

I don't understand why `a == b` is False but `np.allclose(a, b)` is True. After all the range of single-precision floating point number is ~10^38. In fact since `np.can_cast(1e20, 'f4')` is True, I would expect that the equality above should be valid.

I imagine this might have to do something with the quirkiness in the representation of floating point numbers, but I don't fully understand what exactly might be going on here internally.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is indeed the floating point representation in binary:

```
In [41]: print('{}'.format(a))
1e+20

In [42]: print('{}'.format(b))
1.00000002004e+20
```

The reason is that in 64 bit a is:

```
0100 0100 0001 0101 1010 1111 0001 1101 0111 1000 1011 0101 1000 1100 01000000
```

with sign bit 0, then 11 bit exponent 100 0100 0001, and the rest for the mantissa. Casting it to 32bit and back for the comparision strips the last bits of the mantissa:

```
0100 0100 0001 0101 1010 1111 0001 1101 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 00000000
```

Comparing floats can thus be misleading as the == operator checks the exact binary equivalence. Depending on your intention, you might consider checking the level of agreement, e.g.:

```
if fabs(a-b) < 1E-6: 
  print('equal')
```

Comment: No, when comparing floating-point values, you should not always compare with a tolerance. There are limited circumstances in which it is appropriate, and it only reduces false negatives at the expense if introducing false positives. So it should never be done without a proper understanding of the trade-offs. This is bad advice.

Comment: The explanation of the effects of floating-point would be better expressed in terms of the mathematical representation (a sign, significand, and power of two) rather than the bits that represent them. The bits are irrelevant, and the bits are not “stripped” when converting; the significand is rounded.

Comment: I agreed that the advice may be misleading I corrected this in an edit.